# Python Script Fails

Tags: python, windows

I am a complete novice at Python and I wish to run a script someone has made up to check against a critical windows vulnerability. I downloaded python and I thought I had downloaded all the modules and everything needed to run this script, but I keep getting an error: Please see below

```
    C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages>zerologon.py Dc_Name IP_address ( I put this here but I edited it for confidentiality)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\zerologon.py", line 3, in <module>
    from impacket.dcerpc.v5 import nrpc, epm
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\impacket\dcerpc\v5\nrpc.py", line 30, in <module>
    from impacket.dcerpc.v5.samr import OLD_LARGE_INTEGER
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\impacket\dcerpc\v5\samr.py", line 29, in <module>
    from impacket.dcerpc.v5.rpcrt import DCERPCException
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\impacket\dcerpc\v5\rpcrt.py", line 24, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Cipher import ARC4
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Cipher._mode_ecb import _create_ecb_cipher
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 35, in <module>
    raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb", """
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\_raw_api.py", line 308, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
    raise OSError("Cannot load native module '%s': %s" % (name, ", ".join(attempts)))
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.cp38-win_amd64.pyd': cannot load library 'C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\..\Cipher\_raw_ecb.cp38-win_amd64.pyd': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'C:\\Users\\bhanney\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cryptodome\\Util\\..\\Cipher\\_raw_ecb.cp38-win_amd64.pyd', Trying '_raw_ecb.pyd': cannot load library 'C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\..\Cipher\_raw_ecb.pyd': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'C:\\Users\\bhanney\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cryptodome\\Util\\..\\Cipher\\_raw_ecb.pyd'
```

Here is a link to the github script: https://github.com/SecuraBV/CVE-2020-1472 , let me know if anyone can assist because I have no clue what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
In particular, off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're a novice at Python, I'll try to help you.. but you should definetely take a look at the links provided in the first comment.

So, after the formalities, let's read your error message together..

```
    C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages>zerologon.py Dc_Name IP_address
```

> the error was caused by this command: `zerologon.py Dc_Name IP_address`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

> traceback will show the error at the top and their dependencies...

```
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\zerologon.py", line 3, in <module>
    from impacket.dcerpc.v5 import nrpc, epm
```

> the first line is located in your script, the `zerologon.py`, at line 3, where you try to run the following command: `from impacket.dcerpc.v5 import nrpc, epm`

```
  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\impacket\dcerpc\v5\nrpc.py", line 30, in <module>
    from impacket.dcerpc.v5.samr import OLD_LARGE_INTEGER

  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\impacket\dcerpc\v5\samr.py", line 29, in <module>
    from impacket.dcerpc.v5.rpcrt import DCERPCException

  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\impacket\dcerpc\v5\rpcrt.py", line 24, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Cipher import ARC4

  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Cipher._mode_ecb import _create_ecb_cipher

  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 35, in <module>
    raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb", "")

  File "C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\_raw_api.py", line 308, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
    raise OSError("Cannot load native module '%s': %s" % (name, ", ".join(attempts)))
```

> and here, in the last "File Error Message", we can see the root of your problem: the file `\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\_raw_api.py`, in line 308, tried to run the command: `load_pycryptodome_raw_lib`, but it generated an `OSError`...

```
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb':
```

> here we can see the `OSError` message: `Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb'`, and the following part shows us the unsuccessful alternative attempts..

```
Trying '_raw_ecb.cp38-win_amd64.pyd': 

cannot load library 'C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\..\Cipher\_raw_ecb.cp38-win_amd64.pyd': error 0x7e.  

Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'C:\\Users\\bhanney\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cryptodome\\Util\\..\\Cipher\\_raw_ecb.cp38-win_amd64.pyd', 

Trying '_raw_ecb.pyd': cannot load library 'C:\Users\bhanney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\..\Cipher\_raw_ecb.pyd': error 0x7e.  

Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'C:\\Users\\bhanney\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cryptodome\\Util\\..\\Cipher\\_raw_ecb.pyd'
```

> Ok, so after executing this reading and understanding routine, we can try to find a solution to your problem, by looking at:

- [Cryptodome Docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Cryptodome Github Issues](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues)

After doing this, you can even specify your search using the `raw_ecb` text, for example... which leads us to this page, that may be very useful for you:

- [ISSUES filtered by "_raw_ecb.pyd"](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues?q=_raw_ecb.pyd)

Or this one:

- [Error loading native modules #185](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues/185)

In this issue, the OP said the following:

> "I solved it by installing the VC++ 2008 Redistributable as I could see
> in dependencywalker that MSVCR90 was not found"

I know this doesn't clearly answer your question, but it may help you understand how you can fix your code in a more general way..